# Coax directly to box vs. through face plate?

Tags: tv-antenna, coaxial-cable, cable-management

I am running new coax to reroute it so it doesn't run across my family room. I am curious what is the purpose of using a coax jack face plate instead of using a face plate with a flexible opening to just run the original cable directly to the box from the antenna? Something like this...

https://www.homedepot.com/p/Commercial-Electric-Flexible-Opening-Cable-Wall-Plate-White-5028-WH/206456258

I would think the less connections in the line the stronger signal? Thanks for clarifying this!

Comment: Technically, yes, but practically, it will make little difference. Face plates are good for clean cable routing through a house while pass-throughs are good when you want to change the type of cable (ex. upgrading your AV equipment from component cable to HDMI)

Comment: I agree with @HariGanti that the loss factor is nil if you’re using professional grade crimped on coax connectors, installed correctly, and quality barrels (or wall plates).  There is A LOT junky video/coax accessories sold in big box stores tho, watch out.  Be sure to tighten all connections just past finger tight too.

Comment: It's for when you're *not* using the cable. The connector looks professional and finished.  The cable dangling out a  hole in the wall (gussied up with a cover plate or not) looks trailer-trash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every join in the cable reduces the signal strength.

At 1200 Mhz satellite cable frequencies it's about 1dB for a F connector pass-thru at UHF and VHF frequencies the loss is less.

That's probably not going to harm your TV reception noticeably.
a wall plate or skirting socket is going to look better than just a wire coming out of the floor/wall, but yeah, usually you're looking at the front side of the telly, not the back.